# Recreating buttonsets. Should I destroy before?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI (1.8.16) extensively in my application.

I've developed a simple function which fetches some json data with an ajax call and converts a DIV in a pager using jQuery UI buttonsets:

```
<div id="answersPager"></div>
```

this is the javascript:

```
BuildAnswersPager: function(selectedPage, totalPages) {
    $("#answersPager").empty();
    if (totalPages > 1) {
    var ctl = [];
    var isChecked = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        if (i === selectedPage) {
        isChecked = " checked='checked'";
        }
        else {
        isChecked = "";
        }
        ctl[i] = "<input class='answersRadioPager' type='radio' value='" + i + "' id='a_page_" + i + "' name='answer_pager' " + isChecked + "/><label for='a_page_" + i + "'>" + i + "</label>";
    }
    $("#answersPager").append(ctl.join(''));
    $("#answersPager").buttonset();
    }
}
```

I've bound each button to a live click event so that every time a user searches for a new term, I reload the window, build a new pager and allow him/her to page the results.

```
$(".answersRadioPager").live('click', function() {
   // Fetches json data (new page)
});
```

Everything works fine but I was wondering if I have to destroy the buttonset before I rebuild it (at the moment I just empty it).

Are there any memory issues I must be aware of ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. `.empty` removes all data and handlers attached to any removed markup via jQuery's internal `.cleanData` method thereby preventing any memory leaks, so you are quite safe. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data
>   and event handlers from the child elements before removing the
>   elements themselves.

FYI - `.html` also invokes `.cleanData`, so using `.html('')` is equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

A buttonset(), even if never attached to a parent node, will not mark itself as ready for garbage collection.

Try:

- Take a heap snapshot.
- Instantiate n buttonsets, but don't attach to
  any parents, nor add any listeners.
- Take a heap snapshot.
- Compare the two snapshots and note the delta of HTMLButtons has increased.

I have found it requires calling buttonset('destroy') to remedy the situation.